# Android compatible screen and density

Tags: java, android, screen

I just finished my game and published it but it won't work on any screen less than the size  of a tablet.  It says it is due to my manifest settings

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="unjustentertainment.com.GameActivity"
              android:label="My.Game"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
              >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<supports-screens
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="9"/>
 </manifest>
```

But I don't see why I am mainly targeting the htc evo?

Answer (score 1):

if you want this for as many devices as possible remove the "Supports-screen" and you dont really need targetSDK either. If you dont include them it will assume you support them

hopefully that fixes it

Comment: https://market.android.com/details?id=unjustentertainment.com&feature=search_result  ... I got it to work here is my game thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the  element is ignored because you're setting the minSdkVersion to 3; from  [Market filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html):

> For applications that set either the android: minSdkVersion or
>   android: targetSdkVersion to 3 or lower, the 
>   element itself is undefined and no attributes are available. In this
>   case, Market assumes that the application is designed for normal-size
>   screens and shows the application to devices that have normal or
>   larger screens.

Try changing minSdkVersion to 4 and I believe that should fix it.

Comment: I Got It Thank you If you wanna show some support download the lite version of the game here thank you

Comment: Glad it works! Do you have the URL to the game? Also, please click the big checkbox on the left if I answered your question.